# How do I measure CPU usage and memory percentage versus time on linux?

Tags: linux

I would like to plot the CPU and memory usage of an application on linux vs time. What is the best way to do this?

Would `grep`ing these values out from `top` every 0.1s and writing them into some file work - or is there a better and easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way.  All of the information displayed in `top` can be found in `/proc/<pid>/`, most of it in `/proc/<pid>/stat`.  [man proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) describes the content of these files.